# How to prevent access to specific JMS queue on weblogic

Tags: security, ejb, weblogic-10.x

I have a JMS server with queues. For one queue i want to set the access for storing messages based on IP address.
I tried to use context policy based on `_com.bea.contextelement.channel.RemoteAddress_` context filter on the mentioned queue. This setting allowed to send messages from a specific machine only, but then the MDB attached and running on this queue is disconnected and messages are not consumed and processed.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

for record:

i resolved this issue via custom properties in JMS message and completely leave context filter implementation.
The sender is creating a custom property with the value of sender hostname and consumer on target queue is validating the value from this custom property against some list of allowed hostnames.